# Save the text of a text field and then open a file on my device

Tags: android, file, search

I want to save the text the user puts in a text field and then compare it's strings with the names of the files located in a directory on my android device.

If it finds a file with the same name in that directory then it opens. (for now it would be a text file)

I would really appreciate to know, what should I do or how?

Comment: you want someone to write complete code for you or you ran into specific issue?

Comment: Regardless of being new to the language, please show what you have tried. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For a starting reference, you can read about [Android Data Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
public void getServerDetail() {
        try {
            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/RecordData.dat");
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] tokens = strLine.split(",");
                    dbName = tokens[0];
                    serverip = tokens[1];
                    serverport = tokens[2];
                    username = tokens[3];
                    password = tokens[4];
            }
            fstream.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Then use

```
if(Edittext.getText().toString().Equals(password)){}
```

Comment: There are more preferred ways to get the directory of the sdcard

Comment: I want to know what is the program doing from the FileInputStream line to the BufferedReader line?

Comment: oh and Maxim I just want to know, how to use the text of the text field to open a file on some directory

Comment: You means `addTextChangedListener?`